# How to move math symbols vertically and horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, symbols, vertical-alignment, positioning

How do I move the double arrow horizontally to the right?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
{\begin{align}
\underset{u(t), \eta(t), r}{\text{min}}&\quad\int_{0}^{t_f}y^Ty dt\nonumber\\
\text{s.t:}&\quad \int_{0}^{t_f} u^Tu\leq f_{1,k}\nonumber\\
&\quad\eta(0)=(-1,-1,0,0,0,0)\nonumber\\ 
&\quad\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\nonumber\\
&\quad t_f = 10\nonumber\\  
\raisebox{29ex}[10pt][10ex]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$}\nonumber
\end{align}}
&
{\begin{align}
\underset{u(t), \eta(t), r}{\text{min}}&\quad z_2(t_f)\nonumber\\
\text{s.t:}&\quad z_1(t_f)-\phi\leq0\nonumber\\
&\quad z(0)=0\nonumber\\
&\quad\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\nonumber\\
&\quad t_f = 10\nonumber
\end{align}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where you like to have `\Longrightarrow`?

Comment: it is shown just on top of left "min" word..I just edited it

Comment: @S.nic: Do you want it between the two constructions, vertically centred?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. All of them are very useful with there own style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original display is at the top, with my suggested alteration at the bottom:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
{\begin{align}
\underset{u(t), \eta(t), r}{\text{min}}&\quad\int_{0}^{t_f}y^Ty dt\nonumber\\
\text{s.t:}&\quad \int_{0}^{t_f} u^Tu\leq f_{1,k}\nonumber\\
&\quad\eta(0)=(-1,-1,0,0,0,0)\nonumber\\ 
&\quad\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\nonumber\\
&\quad t_f = 10\nonumber\\  
\raisebox{29ex}[10pt][10ex]{$\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}$}\nonumber
\end{align}}
&
{\begin{align}
\underset{u(t), \eta(t), r}{\text{min}}&\quad z_2(t_f)\nonumber\\
\text{s.t:}&\quad z_1(t_f)-\phi\leq0\nonumber\\
&\quad z(0)=0\nonumber\\
&\quad\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\nonumber\\
&\quad t_f = 10\nonumber
\end{align}}
\end{tabular}


\[
  \begin{aligned}
    \min_{u(t), \eta(t), r} \quad & \int_{0}^{t_f}y^Ty \mathrm{d}t \\
    \text{s.t:} \quad & \int_{0}^{t_f} u^Tu \leq f_{1,k} \\
    & \eta(0) = (-1,-1,0,0,0,0) \\ 
    & \frac{\mathrm{d}\eta}{\mathrm{d}t} = A\eta + Bu \\
    & t_f = 10  
  \end{aligned} \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad
  \begin{aligned}
    \min_{u(t), \eta(t), r} \quad & z_2(t_f) \\
    \text{s.t:} \quad & z_1(t_f)-\phi \leq 0 \\
    & z(0) = 0\\
    & \frac{\mathrm{d}\eta}{\mathrm{d}t} = A\eta + Bu \\
    & t_f = 10
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note the use of the `\min` operator (which doesn't require `\underset`).

`aligned` automatically centers its contents vertically. If you want them `t`op-aligned with a vertically-centered `\Longrightarrow`, then you can use something like

```
\begin{aligned}[t]
  ...
\end{aligned}
\qquad \raisebox{-3\baslelineskip}{$\Longrightarrow$} \qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
  ...
\end{aligned}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses two `minipage` environments to house the `align*` environments. Note the use of `\vphantom`s in the right-hand `minipage` to ensure that the equations' rows line up across the two sets of equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\tran{{}^T\!} % well-spaced transpose op.
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{align*}
\min_{u(t), \eta(t), r} \quad 
&\int_{0}^{t_f}y\tran y\, dt\\
\text{s.t: }\quad 
&\int_{0}^{t_f} u\tran u\leq f_{1,k}\\
&\eta(0)=(-1,-1,0,0,0,0)\\ 
&\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\\
& t_f = 10
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\qquad$\Longrightarrow$
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\begin{align*}
\min_{u(t), \eta(t), r}\quad 
&z_2(t_f) \vphantom{\int_{0}^{t_f}}\\
\text{s.t: }\quad 
&z_1(t_f)-\phi\leq0 \vphantom{\int_{0}^{t_f}}\\
&z(0)=0\\
&\frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\\
&t_f = 10
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, one more possible solution:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}%preview enable showing math
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath too

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\min_{u(t),\eta(t),r}
    &\quad  \int_{0}^{t_f} y^Ty dt 
        &\Longrightarrow    &&
\min_{u(t),\eta(t),r}
    &\quad   z_2(t_f)                           \\
%        
\text{s.t:}
    &\quad  \int_{0}^{t_f} u^Tu \leq f_{1,k}    
        &&&
\text{s.t:}
    &\quad   z_1(t_f)-\phi\leq                  \\
%
    &\quad  \eta(0) = (-1,-1,0,0,0,0)           
        &&&
    &\quad   z(0)=0                             \\
%
    &\quad  \frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu           
        &&&
    &\quad   \frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu          \\
%
    &\quad  t_f = 10                            
        &&&
    &\quad   t_f = 10
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

I assume, that `Longarrow` belong to first equation line ... With use of one align environment the equation lines are vertically aligned.

Comment: this makes sense to me.  i'd make a small adjustment though -- the space around the arrow is visually uneven, mainly because of the very long element on the third line on the left.  i'd move the arrow to the left with a negative `\hspace` (or better, `\mspace`), and add some space to the right of the arrow to compensate.  needs experimentation to get it looking good.

Comment: @Barbara, you have right. I will put arrow between ampersands: `&\Longrightarrow &&`, see mo corrected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you mean, with a simpler code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\!\min_{\mathclap {u(t), \eta(t), r}}\quad\int_{0}^{t_f}y^Ty dt\\
  & \text{\footnotesize s. t. \enspace}\mathrlap{\medmath{\begin{array}[t]{|l}
  \int_{0}^{t_f} u^Tu\leq f_{1,k}\\
  \eta(0)=(-1,-1,0,0,0,0)\\
  \frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\\
  t_f = 10
  \end{array}}}
  \end{aligned}
    & & \boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}%
    & &
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\!\min_{\mathclap {u(t), \eta(t), r}} \quad z_2(t_f)\\
  &\text{\footnotesize s. t.\enspace}\medmath{\begin{array}[t]{|l}
  z_1(t_f)-\phi\leq0\\
  z(0)=0\\
  \frac{d\eta}{dt}=A\eta+Bu\\
  t_f = 10
  \end{array}}
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]